# What does main() return?

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What should main() return in C/C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-c)

What value does this function return. just plain main.

```
main()
{
...
}
```

and if a function has two mains , what happens?

Comment: _"If a function has *two* mains"_?

Comment: Obviously the first 'main' gets priority, unless you set the 'FirstMain' property on the second 'main', then order doesn't matter

Comment: I would counter your question with, _why_? Why would you put two mains in when it won't compile? Why not follow the standard and just have one main returning an int?

Comment: I would nt do that, this was asked in my interview

Answer (score 4):

> What value does this function return.

`main` needs to be declared as returning an `int`. The return value is passed to the caller, which is usually the operating system.

> 5.1.2.2.1 [Program startup](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf)
>
> The function called at program startup is named main. The implementation declares no
>   prototype for this function. It shall be defined with a return type of int and with no
>   parameters:

```
int main(void) { /* ... */ }
```

> or with two parameters (referred to here as argc and argv, though any names may be
>   used, as they are local to the function in which they are declared):

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { /* ... */ }
```

---

> and if a function has two mains , what happens?

Linker reports an error.

Answer (score 1):

In C99/C11, `main` returns `0` if the `}` is reached in a hosted environment,. Else, the return value is undefined.

> **C11, § 5.1.2.2.2 Program execution**
>
> [...] reaching the `}` that terminates the `main` function returns a value of 0.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using a C89 or earlier compiler, then

```
main()
{
  ...
}
```

returns `int`.  If you're using a C99 or later compiler, it's an error.

As of C99, if you reach the ending `}` of `main` without an explicit return, the return value is 0.  Not sure about C89 or earlier.

Not sure what "a function has two mains" is supposed to mean.  If a *program* has two `main` functions defined, then you'll most likely get a duplicate definition error at link time.